# coloring different layers of svg file in as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, svg

I have a project in which the different layers of an svg file need to be colored. I tried doing a color transform but it just puts an overlay of color on top of the svg image. Is there anything which can be doe to programmatically color the various layers of an svg file with different colors in AS3?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think Flash has native support of SVG. How do load the file?

Comment: I am using this to display svg's - http://www.flowde.com/blog-examples/svg/

Comment: That doesn't really explain anything. Do you expect anyone to decompile the SWF? Are you using some kind of library to render the SVG?

Comment: No...why would anyone decompile the code? The source code is available on the same site...you just have to look for it. Hmmm...found it. The source is here - http://www.flowde.com/blog-examples/svg/svgViewer.rar and the article is here- http://www.flowde.com/blog/2008/04/13/svg-as3-viewer/

Answer (score 2):

SVG is an XML format, so Flash can read it.  However, Adobe has stopped supporting SVG in general (except for Illustrator and a couple of others), so it is really is a mixed bag whether you can do one specific thing or another.

Concerning the svgViewer that you are using, it uses a recursive method in the `com.flowde.svg.svgViewer` class called `addSVGNodeToMC()` to process the SVG's XML.  This method either draws something, recurses, or whatever.

Looking at the SVG, a few of the files use SVG groups ([read up on it here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#Groups)) . . . is that what you mean by layers?  If so, then that `addSVGNodeToMC()` does have an entry in the `switch()` command for `<g>` markups.  So this is where you (probably) should hijack the code for coloring.

But there is a question of how colors are being used.  In SVG, you can use the attribute method, or `style="*style def*"` method.  The `getStyle()` method converts this XML formatting into a generic object (think of it as a map, with the style name as the key and the style value as the map's entry's value).  Using the method `getCombinedStyle(styleA, styleB)`, two different styles are combined, with all entries in `styleB` overwriting any matching style name in `styleA`.  And you can call `getCombinedStyle()` as often as you want.

This combined style object is eventually passed to `initSetStyle()`, which converts it into AS3/Flash styles.

So it looks like a good interrupt would be to build an `Object` with the style coloring you want, and use `getCombinedStyle(styleA, yourStyleObject)`.  This code should have some functionality to distinguish between different groups, so you could use the group's id attribute, or whatever, to establish the color.  To color the stroke or fill:

```
private function setYourGroupStyle(st, groupId){
    var yourStyleObject:Object = new Object();

    // for the stroke color:
    // In place of simply setting the color value, 
    // you could create another method like 
    // someColorFunctionality(groupId) and call that here.
    yourStyleObject['stroke'] = "#ff0000"; 

    // for the fill color:
    yourStyleObject['fill'] = "#ff0000"; 

    return getCombinedStyle(st, yourStyleObject);
}
```

You would call that function like:

```
[...]
case "g":
    st = setYourGroupStyle(st, node.attribute("id"));

    child=new Sprite();
    for each(var el:XML in node.elements()){
        var c2=addSVGNodeToMC(el,child,st);
        if(c2) child.addChild(c2);
    }
break;
[...]
```

Note that the value `groupId` could be anything, so you could set it up as a tally counter of some sort (e.g., `st = setYourGroupStyle(st, level++);`), and then define what happens based on that value.

But you might want to get permission in writing to use this class. I am not finding any license agreement for it, which puts you in legal limbo.  If it is for a commercial project, it is well worth the time spent getting permission.

HTH!